# How do I get an mp3 to play in a status update from the Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, mp3

Facebook has this nice feature, that if I paste the link of an mp3 file into my status update, it generates this nice little mp3 player.

For example, paste this link into your status box, and you will see a song named "intro" play on your Facebook wall.

http://pmtmobile.sergata.net/content/songs/4084_Intro.mp3

All very cool.

However, I'm trying share this link with the WindowsPhone share tasks, and Facebook does not generate the mp3 player for it. I have tried both ShareLinkTask and ShareStatusTask but neither seem to allow attachments.

It seems, that facebook generates an "attachment" for the status update, but I'm not seeing any information in the C# APIs to add attachments to a status share.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try ShareLinkTask instead of ShareStatusTask. Here also you face issue means, you may need to implement Facebook library manually for your application.

Comment: Thanks, I actually am using ShareLinkTask.  It turns out it's easier just to have a mp3 link with a ► in the title of the name, then to set up an attachment. But if there is a way to do an actual attachment I'd prefer that.

Comment: In that case you may need to build your on Facebook Service

Comment: If you make your comment an Answer I will accept that answer.